# Looking for a formal equivalent phrase for "is considered below"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I like to know a formal equivalent phrase for "is considered below". I spoke with a friend from Ireland, and he said that phrase is not correct for a scientific paper. But, he could not help me with that.

An example is the following.

> "The solution of the problem ___________ [**is considered below**]"

Any suggestions?

Comment: An example sentence would help.

Comment: An example is  the following. "The solution of the problem **is considered below**"

Comment: ...is demonstrated, explored, or examined below.

Comment: @Davo +1 and one might add 'discussed' to the list.

Answer (score 1):

A word which may help here is ***review***. The ODO entry for *review* lists *consider* as a synonym if that helps.

> "The solution to the problem *is **reviewed** below*."

ODO:

> **[review](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/review)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1.2** Survey or evaluate (a subject or past events)
>
> ‘in the next chapter we review a number of recent empirical studies’

Answer (score 0):

You're asking what word or term might go into the blank in place of "is considered below". The word *follows* is used in that context in academic writing.

Here are some examples:

- The discussion follows in Section 5.
  [- Hiroyuki Adachi, On a characterization of stable matchings](http://pareto.uab.es/jmasso/pdf/AdachiEL2000.pdf)
- Eq. (1), therefore, can be rewritten as follows
  [- Ji-Huan He, Homotopy perturbation technique](http://dns2.asia.edu.tw/~ysho/YSHO-English/1000%20China%20(Independent)/PDF/Com%20Met%20App%20Mec%20Eng178,%20257.pdf)